# handling too many categorical features using scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am quite new to scikit-learn and I am trying to use this package to make predictions on the income data.
This maybe a duplicate question as I saw another post on this but I am looking for an easy example to understand what's expected from scikit-learn estimators.

The data I have is of the following structure where many features are categorical (eg: workclass, education..)

```
age: continuous.
workclass: Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov, Local-gov, State-gov, Without-pay, Never-worked.
fnlwgt: continuous.
education: Bachelors, Some-college, 11th, HS-grad, Prof-school, Assoc-acdm, Assoc-voc, 9th, 7th-8th, 12th, Masters, 1st-4th, 10th, Doctorate, 5th-6th, Preschool.
education-num: continuous.
marital-status: Married-civ-spouse, Divorced, Never-married, Separated, Widowed, Married-spouse-absent, Married-AF-spouse.
occupation: Tech-support, Craft-repair, Other-service, Sales, Exec-managerial, Prof-specialty, Handlers-cleaners, Machine-op-inspct, Adm-clerical, Farming-fishing, Transport-moving, Priv-house-serv, Protective-serv, Armed-Forces.
relationship: Wife, Own-child, Husband, Not-in-family, Other-relative, Unmarried.
race: White, Asian-Pac-Islander, Amer-Indian-Eskimo, Other, Black.
sex: Female, Male.
capital-gain: continuous.
capital-loss: continuous.
hours-per-week: continuous.
native-country: United-States, Cambodia, England, Puerto-Rico, Canada, Germany, Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc), India, Japan, Greece, South, China, Cuba, Iran, Honduras, Philippines, Italy, Poland, Jamaica, Vietnam, Mexico, Portugal, Ireland, France, Dominican-Republic, Laos, Ecuador, Taiwan, Haiti, Columbia, Hungary, Guatemala, Nicaragua, Scotland, Thailand, Yugoslavia, El-Salvador, Trinadad&Tobago, Peru, Hong, Holand-Netherlands.
```

Example records:

```
38   Private    215646   HS-grad    9    Divorced    Handlers-cleaners   Not-in-family   White   Male   0   0   40   United-States   <=50K
53   Private    234721   11th   7    Married-civ-spouse  Handlers-cleaners   Husband     Black   Male   0   0   40   United-States   <=50K
30   State-gov  141297   Bachelors  13   Married-civ-spouse  Prof-specialty  Husband     Asian-Pac-Islander  Male   0   0   40   India   >50K
```

I am having a hard time handling the categorical features as most of the models in sckit-learn expect all features to be numbers? 
They do provide some classes to transform/encode such features (like Onehotencoder, DictVectorizer) but I cannot find a way to use these on my data. I know there are quite a number of steps involved here before I fully encode them to numbers but I am just wondering if anybody knows a simpler and efficient(since there are too many such features) way that can be understood with an example.
I vaguely know DictVectorizer is the way to go but need help in how to proceed here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some example code using `DictVectorizer`. First, let set up some data in the Python shell. I leave reading from a file up to you.

```
>>> features = ["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education-num", "marital-status", "occupation",
...             "relationship", "race", "sex", "capital-gain", "capital-loss", "hours-per-week", "native-country"]
>>> input_text = """38   Private    215646   HS-grad    9    Divorced    Handlers-cleaners   Not-in-family   White   Male   0   0   40   United-States   <=50K
... 53   Private    234721   11th   7    Married-civ-spouse  Handlers-cleaners   Husband     Black   Male   0   0   40   United-States   <=50K
... 30   State-gov  141297   Bachelors  13   Married-civ-spouse  Prof-specialty  Husband     Asian-Pac-Islander  Male   0   0   40   India   >50K
... """
```

Now, parse these:

```
>>> for ln in input_text.splitlines():
...     values = ln.split()
...     y.append(values[-1])
...     d = dict(zip(features, values[:-1]))
...     samples.append(d)
```

What have we got now? Let's check:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(samples[0])
{'age': '38',
 'capital-gain': '0',
 'capital-loss': '0',
 'education': 'HS-grad',
 'education-num': '9',
 'fnlwgt': '215646',
 'hours-per-week': '40',
 'marital-status': 'Divorced',
 'native-country': 'United-States',
 'occupation': 'Handlers-cleaners',
 'race': 'White',
 'relationship': 'Not-in-family',
 'sex': 'Male',
 'workclass': 'Private'}
>>> print(y)
['<=50K', '<=50K', '>50K']
```

These `samples` are ready for `DictVectorizer`, so pass them:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> dv = DictVectorizer()
>>> X = dv.fit_transform(samples)
>>> X
<3x29 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 42 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Et voila, you have `X` and `y` that can be passed to an estimator, provided it supports sparse matrices. (Otherwise, pass `sparse=False` to the `DictVectorizer` constructor.)

Test samples can similarly be passed to `DictVectorizer.transform`; if there are feature/value combinations in the test set that do not occur in the training set, these will simply be ignored (because the learned model cannot do anything sensible with them anyway).