# Is it possible to use labelled data in SKLearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

Currently my code looks like:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

However X is an array like:

```
X = [[0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

I would prefer to use X like:

```
X = [{'avg': 0, 'stddev': 1}, {'avg': 1, 'stddev': 1}]
```

Simply because plotting a tree (as described here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification ) makes much more sense when you read `X[0]['avg']` rather than `X[0][0]`. Is it possible? Using dictionary or pandas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) class to convert such a list of dicts to sparse matrices or dense numpy arrays.

scikit-learn will never use dict objects as the primary datastructure to store records internally as this not memory efficient at all compared to numpy arrays or scipy sparse matrices.

Comment: you can use `vectorizer.get_feature_names()` to get the original names of the features that are mapped to the data matrix columns.

Comment: I didn't see you were one of the dev of scikit-learn, many thanks for your work!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231145/handling-too-many-categorical-features-using-scikit-learn/)'s is a great example by 'larsmans' on how to build a feature dict and use DictVectorizer before fitting a model on the data. Note that DictVectorizer class uses scipy.sparse matrix by default (instead of a numpy.ndarray) to make the resulting data structure able to fit in memory. As not all sklearn learning models support sparse matrices you might want to use sparse=False option in the constructor to obtain a dense array

```
dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can specify feature names when using `export_graphviz`. This will generate 
a tree with more meaningful labels at test nodes.

See the `feature_names` parameter at http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz

Comment: Where does one get get the list to supply as the `feature_names` argument?