# A keyword list as a feature in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with many features, one of them is a list of keywords (space separated). 
In Weka you can specify a field as being a list of Strings.
What is the best way to solve this situation in scikit learn?

**Edit:** Note that I have many keywords, creating manually a feature for each is not really an option. If someone can propose a way to create those features (initially I have a pandas dataframe) that would be great.

Comment: So what does WEKA do internally if it doesn't create a feature for each?

Comment: I don't know the details of weka unfortunately, but I'd be surprised if it doesn't do so. My concern is mainly on how to automatically create those features. I will clarify the question.

Comment: [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#common-vectorizer-usage) may be a lead (not necessarily a complete solution)

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19231145/166749) and the accepted answer? (In short: use `DictVectorizer`, don't be afraid of many features, and use an estimator that can handle sparse matrices. The `fit` docstring will contain the word "sparse".) If it doesn't work, please specify what the strings *mean*. I've no idea what Weka does with a list of strings.